# Why am I receiving this error when looping through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I am attempting to loop through two columns in my dataframe and add either a `1` or `0` to a new column based on the two aforementioned column values. For example, if Column A is > Column B then add a `1` to Column C. However, I keep receiving the following error and I'm not sure why.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My code:

```
for i in df.itertuples():
    if df['AdjClose'] > df['30ma']:
        df['position'] = 1
elif df['AdjClose'] < df['30ma']:
    df['position'] = 0
```

Comment: The answers below aren't great. You should use `df['position'] = (df['AdjClose'] > df['30ma']).astype(int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually looping through the rows. In your if statement, instead of your condition being `True` or `False`, it's a Series. Hence, the error. A Series is not true or false, it's a Series. A more correct way to write your code would be

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'AdjClose'] > df.loc[i, '30ma']:
        df.loc[i, 'position'] = 1
    elif df.loc[i, 'AdjClose'] < df.loc[i, '30ma']:
        df.loc[i, 'position'] = 0
```

A shorter, cleaner, and more pandas-y way to write the code that also has the benefit of running faster would be:

```
df.loc[df.AdjClose > df['30ma'], 'position'] = 1
df.loc[df.AdjClose < df['30ma'], 'position'] = 0
```

I highly recommend reading the docs on indexing, it can be a bit tricky in pandas to start with. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Edit:
Note, the for loop code makes the assumption that your index is made of unique values ranging from 0 to n-1. It's a bit more complicated if you have a different index. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix

Comment: This method (like @NaN's original code) will leave 'position' undefined if `df.loc[i, 'AdjClose']==df.loc[i, '30ma']`. But if you want to assign a 0 in that case, you can use an even simpler form: `df['position'] = (df.AdjClose > df['30ma']).astype(int)`. This makes a series showing `True` for all rows where the expression is true, and `False` otherwise. Then `.astype(int)` converts this into 0/1 values.

Comment: `df.loc[]` requires index elements, but your first example is sending it integer offsets instead. This won't work if the rows are indexed in some other way. You could fix that by using `for i in df.index:...`.

Comment: Matthias, you are correct about df.loc, and I mention as such in my edit. `for i in df.index` would not work in the case of repeated indexes though. `for i in range(len(df))` with iloc used in the actual loop would be preferred to make it general for all indexes.

Comment: Ian, good point about repeated indexes. That would be a tricky case to handle via a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling `df.itertuples`, but not using the result. You could fix that using one of Ian Kent's suggestions, or something like this:

```
for row in df[['AdjClose', '30ma']].itertuples():
    if row[1] > row[2]:  # note: row[0] is the index value
        df.loc[row.Index, 'position'] = 1
    elif row[1] < row[2]:
        df.loc[row.Index, 'position'] = 0
```

If your columns all had names that were valid Python identifiers, you could use something neater:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.AdjClose > row.ma30:
        df.loc[row.Index, 'position'] = 1
    elif row.AdjClose < row.ma30:
        df.loc[row.Index, 'position'] = 0
```

Note that neither of these will work if the index for `df` has duplicate values.

You might also be able to use `df.apply`, like this:

```
def pos(row):
    if row['AdjClose'] > row['30ma']:
        return 1
    elif row['AdjClose'] > row['30ma']:
        return 0
    else:
        return pd.np.nan  # undefined?

df['position'] = df.apply(pos)
```

or just

```
df['position'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['AdjClose'] > row['30ma'] else 0)
```

This should work even if the index has duplicate values. However, you have to define a value for every row, even the ones where `row['AdjClose'] == row['30ma']`.

Overall, you're probably best off with Ian Kent's second recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to test a boolean over multiple values (similar to `if pd.Series([False, True, False])` which is not clear what the result is), so pandas raises that error.

The message suggests you could use `any()` to return if any value (in this case the one value you're testing) is `True`.

So maybe something like this:

```
for i in df.itertuples():
    if (df['AdjClose'] > df['30ma']).any():
        df['position'] = 1
    elif (df['AdjClose'] < df['30ma']).any():
        df['position'] = 0
```

See these docs for further details [Using If/Truth Statements with pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas)